# Login page doesn't redirect to homepage

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following script:

```
//Possible solution for logging a user in below. 
if($result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT password FROM USERS WHERE password = '". $password ."' AND username = '". $username ."'")){
    $count = $result->num_rows;
    $accounttype = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT AccountType FROM USERS WHERE username ='". $username."'");
    if($count>=1){
        if($accounttype == "tradesmen"){
            include('../html/WelcomeCustomer.html');
        }
        else if($accounttype == "customer"){
            include('../html/WelcomeTrade.html');
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "The login credentials were incorrect";
    }
}
```

I know there is a more than a few things wrong with this implementation in terms of security. I plan on fixing this once I have the login working.

For now I just wish to get the user logged in. When I run this I get a blank page, using the following accounts:

```
username, password, AccountType: test, test, tradesmen. 
username, password, AccountType: work, work, customer.
```

I have error reporting turned on and I get nothing. What could be the reason for the script not redirecting the user?

Answer (score 0):

well, you're not `redirecting` the control. This statement `include('../html/WelcomeCustomer.html');` will just `include` the `HTML` file rather than `redirecting` to it.

So you need to do following. also you don't need to double query the database

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "db_name");
$result = $mysqli->query($db,"SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE password = '". $password ."' AND username = '". $username ."'");
$count = $result->num_rows;
if($count){
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if($row['AccountType'] == "tradesmen"){
        header('Location: ../html/WelcomeCustomer.html');
    }
    else if($row['AccountType'] == "customer"){
        header('Location: ../html/WelcomeTrade.html');
    }
}
else{
    echo "The login credentials were incorrect";
}
```

}

**just change your `include` statements**
I found that you're direct matching the `object` inside `if` condition, you need to first `fetch` data and after that compare it.

**IMPORTANT**

at some places, you're using ***Object oriented style*** like ***$result->num_rows;*** and at some places you're using ***Procedural style*** like ***mysqli_query***. So I suggest you to use one of them, I've updated my answer with ***Object oriented style***

Comment: So I changed them and still get a blank white screen with no errors. Before I was logging in based on account type, I only had one homepage and include was working then.

Comment: With you revised code, only the first if and else is working. The else if always brings up a white screen with no errors.

Comment: if there are only two types in the database, just use `else`

Comment: $accountype needs defining as a variable